# Convert the text position in PDF file from Points to inches(Same measure as OCR uses) using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, ocr

I have a PDF file
I am reading Text from PDF file pro-grammatically using iTextSharp class.
iTextSharp uses “points” as the unit of measurement.
Using  iTextSharp class , I have coordinates of one letter in my PDF file is as below(Units of Points):

PosLeft   : 78
PosRight : 87.19082
PosTop  : 541.3443
PosBottom  : 530.3043
FontSize : 8.344299

I have the application to read the PDF file with OCR.
I read the same PDF file using OCR.
Using  OCR , I have coordinates of the same above letter in my PDF file is as below(Units of Inches):

left : 0.147640177490924
top : 0.360034207525656
width  : 0.00806776926179911
height  :0.00684150513112885
ItemNumber  : 108

So from above,
I have X coordinate in units of “points”  : PosLeft :78   PosRight : 87.19082 using iTextSharp class.
I have X coordinate in units of “Inches”  : 0.147640177490924 using OCR.

My Problem is that above readings does not match with the formula of “1 inch = 72 points” 
What is the formula of Conversion of Points value (PosLeft: 78 ,PosRight :87.19082) to inches value(0.147640177490924).

In the below code I get the values in Points (PosLeft :78   PosRight : 87.19082 ) 
I want to covert the values from Points to Inches and the value must same as OCR reading that is (0.147640177490924).

Below is my code:

```
Public Function ReadPDFFile(ByVal strSource As String) As String

    Dim sbPDFText As New StringBuilder() 'StringBuilder Object To Store read Text

    If File.Exists(strSource) Then 'Does File Exist?
        Dim pdfFileReader As New PdfReader(strSource) 'read File
        For intCurrPage As Integer = 1 To pdfFileReader.NumberOfPages 'Loop Through All Pages

            Dim lteStrategy As LocTextExtractionStrategy = New LocTextExtractionStrategy 'Read PDF File Content Blocks
            'Get Text
            Dim strCurrText As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfFileReader, intCurrPage, lteStrategy)

            sbPDFText.Append(strCurrText) 'Add Text To String Builder
        Next
        pdfFileReader.Close() 'Close File
    End If
    Return sbPDFText.ToString() 'Return 

End Function


Public Overridable Sub RenderText(ByVal renderInfo As TextRenderInfo) Implements    ITextExtractionStrategy.RenderText

    Dim segment As LineSegment = renderInfo.GetBaseline()
    Dim location As New TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), segment.GetStartPoint(), segment.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth())

    If renderInfo.GetText = "" Then
        Console.WriteLine(GetResultantText())
    End If
    With location
        'Chunk Location:
        Debug.Print(renderInfo.GetText)
        .PosLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine.GetStartPoint(Vector.I1)
        .PosRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine.GetEndPoint(Vector.I1)
        .PosBottom = renderInfo.GetDescentLine.GetStartPoint(Vector.I2)
        .PosTop = renderInfo.GetAscentLine.GetEndPoint(Vector.I2)
        'Chunk Font Size: (Height)
        .curFontSize = .PosTop - segment.GetStartPoint()(Vector.I2)
        'Use Font name  and Size as Key in the SortedList
        Dim StrKey As String = renderInfo.GetFont.PostscriptFontName & .curFontSize.ToString
        'Add this font to ThisPdfDocFonts SortedList if it's not already present
        If 1 = 1 Then
            If Not ThisPdfDocFonts.ContainsKey(StrKey) Then ThisPdfDocFonts.Add(StrKey, renderInfo.GetFont)
            'Store the SortedList index in this Chunk, so we can get it later
            .FontIndex = ThisPdfDocFonts.IndexOfKey(StrKey)
            Console.WriteLine(renderInfo.GetFont.ToString & "-->" & StrKey)
        Else
            'pcbContent.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 9)
            .FontIndex = 3
            .curFontSize = 8
        End If
    End With
    locationalResult.Add(location)

End Sub
```

Comment: All coordinates can be transformed in a PDF; not only the zero point, but also their scale. So 1 *unit* may not be 1 point. Can you provide a link to this PDF?

Comment: Do you have a larger entity which you could get test values from, such as a four inch square box? I suspect that the PDF will use the coordinates of the bounding box of a character, whereas OCR could use the coordinates of what is printed. A large item with hard edges should eliminate the bounding-box problem, give less relative error from scanning, and allow you to see if the scan gives an accurate aspect ratio.

Comment: Please find the link of PDF file below:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxMXYx85sXDVWFhNYjhMSnNmcUk/edit

The coordinate values i have mentioned above is for "M" letter of "Muy señores nuestros:" text in the PDF file. 
Thank You  Jongware 
Thank You Andrew Morton

Comment: Your first concern should be finding out (from the manual?) the meaning of the data output by the OCR solution. Obviously, by eyesight, you can see that the ''M'' is positioned about an inch from the left of the document (which coincides well with the output of iText), so the OCR output *left : 0.147640177490924* either is not in relation to the document border or uses a different unit than inches. The sitution is analogous for the *top : 0.360034207525656* value. The width and height cannot be in inches, take a ruler and draw a line 0.00806776926179911 inches long. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yes I have analyzed the situation. I think the output of OCR is not in units of inches.
So what should be the relation between OCR output(left :0.147640177490924,top:0.360034207525656) and iTextSharp output(PosLeft : 78,PosRight : 87.19082) values.

Comment: Is the OCR engine operating on the PDF file or the original image? Might be the OCR units are in terms of resolution reported by the original image file - and likely as not, the resolution in the original file is wrong.

Comment: @WNET Please find out (e.g. from the manual) what the OCR solution output means, i.e. which units it uses and the position of which point of the letter is used in which relation to which fixed point.

Comment: Were you really comparing (left,top) against (left,right), 3 comments up? *Unify* your coordinates. You are also using (left,right) vs. (left,width), *and* an inverted y-axis for one set of coords, in your original post.

Comment: @Jongware :  I have OCR output value left :0.147640177490924 and iTextSharp output value PosLeft : 78,PosRight : 87.19082 for X cordinate.
I have OCR output value top : 0.360034207525656 and iTextSharp output value PosTop : 541.3443 PosBottom : 530.3043 for Y cordinate.

Comment: What should be the relation between  OCR output value left :0.147640177490924 and iTextSharp output value PosLeft : 78,PosRight : 87.19082?

Comment: @plinth  : I converted this PDF file to tif and I applied OCR on  image converted from the PDF.

Comment: the OCR output value is applied on image file converted from PDF file.
How OCR output value left :0.147640177490924 is related to iTextSharp output value PosLeft : 78,PosRight : 87.19082.